# Tabbed slider carousel not working in bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I tried to implement this code:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/tabbed-slider-carousel

The only difference: I am using these imports:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This is my code:

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
        </ul>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

         <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->





    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval:   4000
    });

    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
            clickEvent = true;
            $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        if(!clickEvent) {
            var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
            var current = $('.nav li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
            if(count == id) {
                $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');    
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;
    });
});
```

css:

```
body { padding-top: 20px; }
#myCarousel .nav a small {
    display:block;
}
#myCarousel .nav {
    background:#eee;
}
#myCarousel .nav a {
    border-radius:0px;
}
```

Please have a look at the result in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ku1jhk9/1/

There you can see, that it somehow does not work. BUT I don't get any errors in my console. So I am left clueless.

Does anyone know why it does not work with bootstrap 4 and what I would need to change?

Comment: You're missing some of the HTML, try pasting the original HTML in there, it will still look a little wonky, but nothing too hard to fix and it works. Edit: Here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/2ku1jhk9/3/

Comment: @Maharkus Now you just imported boostrap 3 :D I know that it is working with that. My whole question is how to get it running with bootstrap 4

Comment: I didn't realize the snippet was made in Bootstrap3 my bad haha. But still, the only thing you would be changing then is the HTML, which would mean that technically it is still Bootstrap 4.

Comment: @Maharkus I don't know what you are trying to say.

Comment: Bootstrap4 has different implementation like changed class name etc. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Bootstrap4` carousel having a small change in the code. All the carousel item classes should changed from `item` to `carousel-item`. Look at the code

```
<div class="item">
```

should changed to

```
<div class="carousel-item">
```

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval:   4000
 });
 
 var clickEvent = false;
 $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
   clickEvent = true;
   $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');  
 }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
  if(!clickEvent) {
   var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
   var current = $('.nav li.active');
   current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
   var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
   if(count == id) {
    $('.nav li').first().addClass('active'); 
   }
  }
  clickEvent = false;
 });
});
```

```css
body { padding-top: 20px; }
#myCarousel .nav a small {
    display:block;
}
#myCarousel .nav {
 background:#eee;
}
#myCarousel .nav a {
    border-radius:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
        </ul>
    
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
 
         <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
        
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
        
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
                
      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
</div>
```

Here is the [**Fiddle version**](https://jsfiddle.net/2ku1jhk9/13/).

Comment: Wow, this is great. Do you also know how to fix the missing blue background color at the active tab?

Comment: I am not sure what `boostrap4.css` have to replace with this? In the above code just go with `bootstrap 3.3.7` for only css. That will fix the issue. Other wise if you want to use only version 4 then time being you can overwrite your own like `#myCarousel .nav-pills>li.active {
  background-color: #428bca;
}
#myCarousel .nav-pills>li.active>a, #myCarousel .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, #myCarousel .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}`